# Retrieve part of string, variable length

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to learn how to use Regular Expressions with Python. I want to retrieve an ID number (in parentheses) in the end from a string that looks like this:

```
"This is a string of variable length (561401)"
```

The ID number (`561401` in this example) can be of variable length, as can the text.

```
"This is another string of variable length (99521199)"
```

My coding fails:

```
import re
import selenium

# [Code omitted here, I use selenium to navigate a web page]

result = driver.find_element_by_class_name("class_name")
print result.text # [This correctly prints the whole string "This is a text of variable length (561401)"]

id = re.findall("??????", result.text) # [Not sure what to do here]
print id
```

Comment: A great resource for this is http://regex101.com

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for your example:

```
(?<=\()[0-9]*
```

`?<=` Matches something preceding the group you are looking for but doesn't consume it.  In this case, I used `\(`.  ( is a special character, so it has to be escaped with `\`.  `[0-9]` matches any number.  The `*` means match any number of the directly preceding rule, so `[0-9]*` means match as many numbers as there are.

Answer (score 2):

Solved this thanks to Kaz's link, very useful:

http://regex101.com/

```
id = re.findall("(\d+)", result.text)
print id[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple solution :

```
>>> originString = "This is a string of variable length (561401)"  
>>> str1=OriginalString.replace("("," ")
'This is a string of variable length  561401)'
>>> str2=str1.replace(")"," ")
'This is a string of variable length  561401 '
>>> [int(s) for s in string.split() if s.isdigit()]
[561401]
```

First, I replace parantheses with space. and then I searched the new string for integers.

Answer (score 1):

No need to really use regular expressions here, if it is always at the end and always in parenthesis you can split, extract last element and remove the parenthesis by taking the substring ([1:-1]). Regexes are relatively time expensive.

```
line = "This is another string of variable length (99521199)"
print line.split()[-1][1:-1]
```

If you did want to use regular expressions I would do this:

```
import re
line = "This is another string of variable length (99521199)"
id_match = re.match('.*\((\d+)\)',line)
if id_match:
    print id_match.group(1)
```